# Do 'Rooster Bakery' and 'Hot Song Karaoke' actually exist?

Tags: sleeping-dogs

Out of curiosity, I started to go around inside the game world to look for shops that are mentioned in some radio commercials (especially those spoken in Cantonese). I looked for the captioned shops but cannot find them anywhere. Anyone spotted them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you can not enter them.

Comment: Why did you vote me down. That's the correct answer.

Comment: What proof do you have that this is correct?  Do you have a source?

Comment: I went to the places tried all possible angles [except for the roof].

Comment: The only doors there don't open I even tried firing at them

Comment: I'd recommend adding that your answer.  I still don't think that's proof, but others might.

Answer (score -2):

I went looking too, but I couldn't find any. I've found all the health shrines, if that's any indication on how much traveling I've done.

I thought it was kinda strange because the precedent set by games like GTA etc. would be that the shops exist somewhere in the game.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, they do exist. However, as far as my attempts have gone, you are unable to enter them.